# Declaring a variable in netezza SQL using the @ sign

Tags: sql, variables, netezza

Good day

I am currently trying to programme a dynamic variable that is to be changed at the start of each new region that I run without physically going through each line of code to find where changes are to be made.

I have seen that people make use of a @ notation to temporarily store a value for this type of case. Can someone please assist?

Comment: Hi! I'm not quite sure what a good answer to this question would look like - are you looking for a general tutorial, or do you have a particular problem that you need help with? Be sure to check the [help] if you haven't already to see the types of questions that are encouraged here.

Comment: Hi IMSoP, I just need a quick fix for a particular problem. I have consulted the Netezza and IBM documentation but can't find the explanation as I am unsure what the method is called. The Netezza platform on our end does not allow us to make use of stored procedures, hence the need for the different way of variable declaration

Comment: In that case, please [edit] your question to describe *that particular problem*. As it is, it seems very broad, because the answer could be anything from "yes, declaring variables with @ is possible" to an entire tutorial on different ways to use them. It would be useful to include references to any pages you've found that didn't help, and why they didn't, so people don't repeat things you already know.

Comment: To be honest, i dont know how to even word it differently from what i have asked. Lets leave it and I will search some more on google for now. Thanks! It seems that the operator was in fact a $ not a @.

Comment: You might also want to check [the search results on this site for `[netezza] + variable`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnetezza%5D+variable) to see if someone else has already asked a similar question.